# How to draw multiple textures per object

Tags: opengl, glsl

How do I apply multiple textures to different faces per object?

*Specifically I draw a cube:*

[image: drawn cube]

**I want to be able to draw a different image (or sub-image) on each different face of the cube.** How would I do this?

*vertex shader:*

```
#version 330 core

uniform vec3 position = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);
}
```

*geometry shader:*

```
#version 330 core

layout(points) in;
layout(triangle_strip, max_vertices=64) out;

out vec2 tex_coord;

uniform mat4x4 model;
uniform mat4x4 view;
uniform mat4x4 projection;

uniform float size = 1.0;

const vec2 texc[4] = vec2[](vec2(0, 0), // texture coordinates
                            vec2(1, 0),
                            vec2(0, 1),
                            vec2(1, 1));

void main() {
    float asize = size / 2;
    vec4 offset[24] = vec4[] (
                            vec4(-asize,  asize, -asize, 0.0), //top face
                            vec4( asize,  asize, -asize, 0.0),
                            vec4(-asize,  asize,  asize, 0.0),
                            vec4( asize,  asize,  asize, 0.0),

                            vec4(-asize, -asize, -asize, 0.0), //bottom face
                            vec4( asize, -asize,  asize, 0.0),
                            vec4(-asize, -asize, -asize, 0.0),
                            vec4( asize, -asize,  asize, 0.0),

                            vec4(-asize,  asize, -asize, 0.0), //left face
                            vec4(-asize,  asize,  asize, 0.0),
                            vec4(-asize, -asize, -asize, 0.0),
                            vec4(-asize, -asize,  asize, 0.0),

                            vec4( asize,  asize, -asize, 0.0), //right face
                            vec4( asize,  asize,  asize, 0.0),
                            vec4( asize, -asize, -asize, 0.0),
                            vec4( asize, -asize,  asize, 0.0),

                            vec4(-asize,  asize,  asize, 0.0), //rear face
                            vec4( asize,  asize,  asize, 0.0),
                            vec4(-asize, -asize,  asize, 0.0),
                            vec4( asize, -asize,  asize, 0.0),

                            vec4(-asize,  asize, -asize, 0.0), //front face
                            vec4( asize,  asize, -asize, 0.0),
                            vec4(-asize, -asize, -asize, 0.0),
                            vec4( asize, -asize, -asize, 0.0));

    int i, j, k;
    for(i = 0; i < gl_in.length(); ++i) {          // for each input vertex generate a cube
        for(k = 0; k < offset.length() / 4; ++k) { // for each face of the cube
            for(j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {               // for each vertex per face
                gl_Position = projection * view * model * (gl_in[i].gl_Position + offset[j + k*4]);
                tex_coord = texc[j];
                EmitVertex();
            }
            EndPrimitive();
        }
    }
}
```

*fragment shader:*

```
#version 330 core

out vec4 fragment_out;
uniform sampler2D tex;
in vec2 tex_coord;

void main() {
    fragment_out = texture(tex, tex_coord);
}
```

Comment: do you want multiple textures per object? or multiple textures per face ?

Comment: @concept3d I want to draw a different texture on each face; One texture per face.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the simplest approach you can take to this problem, since you have a geometry shader:

#### Geometry shader:

```
#version 330 core

layout(points) in;
layout(triangle_strip, max_vertices=64) out;

out vec2 tex_coord;

uniform mat4x4 model;
uniform mat4x4 view;
uniform mat4x4 projection;

uniform float size = 1.0;

const vec2 texc[4] = vec2[](vec2(0, 0), // texture coordinates
                            vec2(1, 0),
                            vec2(0, 1),
                            vec2(1, 1));

void main() {
    float asize = size / 2;
    vec4 offset[24] = vec4[] (
                            vec4(-asize,  asize, -asize, 0.0), //top face
                            vec4( asize,  asize, -asize, 0.0),
                            vec4(-asize,  asize,  asize, 0.0),
                            vec4( asize,  asize,  asize, 0.0),

                            vec4(-asize, -asize, -asize, 0.0), //bottom face
                            vec4( asize, -asize,  asize, 0.0),
                            vec4(-asize, -asize, -asize, 0.0),
                            vec4( asize, -asize,  asize, 0.0),

                            vec4(-asize,  asize, -asize, 0.0), //left face
                            vec4(-asize,  asize,  asize, 0.0),
                            vec4(-asize, -asize, -asize, 0.0),
                            vec4(-asize, -asize,  asize, 0.0),

                            vec4( asize,  asize, -asize, 0.0), //right face
                            vec4( asize,  asize,  asize, 0.0),
                            vec4( asize, -asize, -asize, 0.0),
                            vec4( asize, -asize,  asize, 0.0),

                            vec4(-asize,  asize,  asize, 0.0), //rear face
                            vec4( asize,  asize,  asize, 0.0),
                            vec4(-asize, -asize,  asize, 0.0),
                            vec4( asize, -asize,  asize, 0.0),

                            vec4(-asize,  asize, -asize, 0.0), //front face
                            vec4( asize,  asize, -asize, 0.0),
                            vec4(-asize, -asize, -asize, 0.0),
                            vec4( asize, -asize, -asize, 0.0));

    int i, j, k;
    for(i = 0; i < gl_in.length(); ++i) {          // for each input vertex generate a cube
        for(k = 0; k < offset.length() / 4; ++k) { // for each face of the cube

          gl_PrimitiveID = k; // Must set this, otherwise it will be undefined in the FS

            for(j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {               // for each vertex per face
                gl_Position = projection * view * model * (gl_in[i].gl_Position + offset[j + k*4]);
                tex_coord = texc[j];
                EmitVertex();
            }
            EndPrimitive();
        }
    }
}
```

#### Fragment shader:

```
#version 330 core

out vec4 fragment_out;
uniform sampler2D tex [6];
in vec2 tex_coord;

void main() {
    fragment_out = texture (tex [gl_PrimitiveID], tex_coord);
}
```

Now, just setup 6 different texture image units and you are done.

NOTE: You have to write `gl_PrimitiveID` in the geometry shader or it will be undefined in the fragment shader. So there is 1 additional line in the GS, ordinarily GL would automatically generate this value for you.

Answer (score 1):

First You need to pass two texture units to the shader, and modulate or add them in some way for example:

```
#version 330 core

out vec4 fragment_out;
uniform sampler2D tex;
uniform sampler2D tex2;
in vec2 tex_coord;

void main() {
    fragment_out = texture(tex, tex_coord)*texture(tex2, tex_coord);
}
```

Unfortuantely, this way you will have 2 textures for the same faces. If you want texture per face.

-You can have multiple texture coordinates and use each texture with a set of texcoords in your shader, so instead of one `tex_coord`, you have another `tex_coord2`.

```
#version 330 core    
out vec4 fragment_out;
uniform sampler2D tex;
uniform sampler2D tex2;
in vec2 tex_coord;
in vec2 tex_coord;

void main() {
    fragment_out = texture(tex, tex_coord) + texture(tex2, tex_coord2);
}
```

-The other way is to combine multiple images in one image and alight it so each face has a separate part of the big image.

-The easier way is to deal with each face as a separate object, but this is highly unrecommended.